# Lazy GString evaluation in Groovy closures

Tags: groovy, closures, lazy-evaluation, gstring

I try to understand why in the following snippet, the GString is evaluated fine if it's created inside the closure, but will throw an exception if I try to create the String outside and try to evaluate it inside the closures:

```
map1 = ['foo': 1, 'bar': 2]
map2 = ['foo': 3, 'bar': 4]

dynamicallyGeneratedString = "key1: ${->key1}, val1: ${->value1}, key2: ${->key2}, val2: ${->value2}"

map1.each { key1, value1 ->
    map2.each { key2, value2 ->
        println "key1: ${->key1}, val1: ${->value1}, key2: ${->key2}, val2: ${->value2}" // works as expected
        // println dynamicallyGeneratedString // throws MissingPropertyException
    }
}
```

The desired output in both cases would be:

```
key1: foo, val1: 1, key2: foo, val2: 3
key1: foo, val1: 1, key2: bar, val2: 4
key1: bar, val1: 2, key2: foo, val2: 3
key1: bar, val1: 2, key2: bar, val2: 4
```

My goal is to dynamically generate a String depending on some other conditions, and then to lazily evaluate its contents while looping through the maps.

Is this a valid approach at all?

Comment: Not sure it's possible...  You could use a template engine?  Why does the definition of the string need to be located far away from its usage?

Comment: Just because I'm using a few ifs and elses to assemble the string, and I somehow thought it would be easier to create it only once, instead of testing the conditions for each iteration. But maybe I should not think of optimizing at this step?!

Comment: Sounds like a case for templating?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to using templating as suggested by @Vampire, I can think of two alternative ways of solving the task.

- Re-assigning variables inside the closure:

  ```
  map1 = ['foo': 1, 'bar': 2]
  map2 = ['foo': 3, 'bar': 4]

  def k1, v1, k2, v2
  dynamicString = "key1: ${->k1}, val1: ${->v1}, key2: ${->k2}, val2: ${->v2}"

  map1.each { key1, value1 ->
      map2.each { key2, value2 ->
          k1 = key1
          v1 = value1
          k2 = key2
          v2 = value2
          println dynamicString
      }
  }
  ```
- Function evaluation:

  ```
  map1 = ['foo': 1, 'bar': 2]
  map2 = ['foo': 3, 'bar': 4]

  def myfunc(key1, value1, key2, value2) {
      dynamicallyGeneratedString = "key1: ${key1}, val1: ${value1}, key2: ${key2}, val2: ${value2}"
  }

  map1.each { key1, value1 ->
      map2.each { key2, value2 ->
          println myfunc(key1, value1, key2, value2)
      }
  }
  ```

I guess it's just a matter of taste... (or are there any performance considerations I am missing?)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, when you create the GString, it stores the references to the variables. When you then try to evaluate it, those refernces point to nothing and you get the exception.

If you really want to do it that way, I think you have to use a template engine like with

```
println new groovy.text.GStringTemplateEngine().createTemplate(dynamicallyGeneratedString).make(key1: key1, value1: value1, key2: key2, value2: value2)
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party but here it is.

I wrote the following class, I use it for dynamically building SQL queries without sacrificing security since fill's result is a **GStringImpl** instance and **groovy.sql.Sql** correctly transforms it into parametrized database query.

I wasn't sure if Closure's **call** method is thread-safe (since I am setting **delegate** property) so I added **synchronized** to the fill method.

```
class GTemplate {

    def compiledTemplate

    GTemplate(String templateSource) {
        compiledTemplate = new GroovyShell().evaluate('{-> """' + escape(templateSource) + '""" }')
    }

    def static GTemplate compile(String templateSource) {
        return new GTemplate(templateSource)
    }

    def synchronized fill(def args) {
        compiledTemplate.delegate = args
        return compiledTemplate.call()
    }

    def synchronized fill(Map<?,?> args) {
        compiledTemplate.delegate = args
        return compiledTemplate.call()
    }

    private static String escape(String str) {
        StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder()
        for(char c : str) {
            if ((c == '"') || (c == '\\'))
                buf.append('\\')
            buf.append(c)
        }
        return buf.toString()
    }
}

map1 = ['foo': 1, 'bar': 2]
map2 = ['foo': 3, 'bar': 4]

dynamicallyGeneratedString = GTemplate.compile('key1: ${->key1}, val1: ${->value1}, key2: ${->key2}, val2: ${->value2}')

map1.each { key1, value1 ->
    map2.each { key2, value2 ->
        println dynamicallyGeneratedString.fill(key1: key1, value1: value1, key2: key2, value2: value2)
    }
}
```